# If I have to submit a urine test does that automatically mean I'll get a background check

Tags: interviewing, hiring-process

I just had an interview and I was told and that I need to have a urinalysis completed I was not told anything about a background check will they later say it

Comment: It's going to depend on the employer and the position.  Some employers do a background check and no drug test.  Some do a drug test and no background check.  Some do both (and different companies have very different definitions of what a background check entails).

Comment: Without a country tag, any answer to this will be meaningless. Depending on country and industry, this can be somewhere between legally required and super shady illegal.

Comment: Only one country thinks urine tests are appropriate for normal jobs.

Answer (score 2):

> If I have to submit a urine test does that automatically mean I'll get
> a background check

No, it doesn't automatically mean that a background test will be required.

Drug tests and background tests are two separate things. In most locales, permission from you would be required before each.

> I was not told anything about a background check will they later say
> it

They may. In some domains, in some locales, it's routine.